# Find out from which column MySQL data came from

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a legacy site I'm keeping up and running for my University and I'm running into a bit of a snag.

I'm building a Rec letter review system, where deans can come in and check off whether or not a letter is good to go or if it needs to be reworked. My problem is as follows:

The database is not normalized at all, and is about 120 columns.
I've gotten all the students who need their letters reviewed, but I cannot tell from which column (e.g. Rec1,Rec2,Rec3...Rec10) it came from. Without knowing which column set off the alarm, per se, I cannot link to it effectively.

I tried using mysql_fetch_field, but I can't quite figure out how to combine that with a SELECT which limits it to the field that contains the recommender ID (Which would be in the proper column and therefore get me the information I need).

Any help is much appreciated. If you need further details just ask below. Thanks.

-samuel

Comment: Go back and fix the database schema. Every other solution will be adding pimples to your warts :-)

Comment: don't I know it D: the thing was built over 3 years by 3 different people, all of whom learned to code by building it. and then I learned to code debugging it. I'd love to shatter the thing and rebuild it properly but it's genuinely not possible given my time constraints. hackathon2012.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using mysql_fetch_field,

try to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: does this return information about the column the data came from? I can't find any reference to such magic in the php Manual.

Comment: oh really? may be I can't get your problem but to me the only purpose of this function is to tell you column names for each retrieved data row

Comment: yeah, the problem is that I need the column name of the column that triggered the row to be pulled to make the data actually useful.

Comment: there are columns Rec1 through Rec10. I feed in an id number, 123456, and match it against all the columns with a SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Rec1='idnumber' OR Rec2='idnumber'- etc. I need to know which one of those columns caused the row to be selected, so which one actually matched it.

Comment: feed the same number to the resulting array. not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_flat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rec1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rec2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rec3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

With initial data:

```
INSERT INTO test_flat VALUES (NULL, 'name 0', '1', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO test_flat VALUES (NULL, 'name 1', '11', '12', '13');

SELECT * FROM test_flat;
+----+--------+------+------+------+
| id | name   | rec1 | rec2 | rec3 |
+----+--------+------+------+------+
|  1 | name 0 | 1    | 2    | 3    |
|  2 | name 1 | 11   | 12   | 13   |
+----+--------+------+------+------+
```

You can:

```
SELECT *, IF (rec1 = '2', 'rec1', IF (rec2 = '2', 'rec2', IF (rec3 = 'rec3', 'rec3', ''))) AS matched FROM test_flat WHERE rec1 = '2' or rec2 = '2' or rec3 = '2';
+----+------+------+------+------+---------+
| id | name | rec1 | rec2 | rec3 | matched |
+----+------+------+------+------+---------+
|  1 | name | 1    | 2    | 3    | rec2    |
+----+------+------+------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you do as Your Common Sense suggests:

```
$value = 'idnumber';

$query = query("SELECT Rec1, Rec2, Rec3 FROM table WHERE {$value} IN (Rec1, Rec2, Rec3)");
$row   = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

foreach(array_keys($row) as $h)
    if ($row[$h] == $value) {
        $column = $h;
        break;
    }
```

And now you have your `$column`!

If there are many columns you can do:

```
$arr_cols = array();
foreach(range(1, 20) as $i)
   $arr_cols[] = "Rec{$i}";

$str_cols = implode(', ', $arr_cols);

$query = query("SELECT {$str_cols} FROM table WHERE {$value} IN ({$str_cols})");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd be tempted to fix the existing mess. As an interim measure:

```
CREATE VIEW norm_rec AS
SELECT t1.id,
       'rec1' AS src_col,
       t1.rec1 as rec
FROM yourtable t1
UNION
SELECT t2.id,
       'rec2' AS src_col,
       t2.rec2 as rec
FROM yourtable t2
UNION
SELECT t3.id,
       'rec3' AS src_col,
       t3.rec3 as rec
FROM yourtable t3
....
```

Depending on how the data is being changed a materialized view would make a lot of sense.